# Cannot get logs from current stage in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Is it possible to get log content from current stage in Jenkins pipeline, and then set status of that current stage based on log content?

I want to do sth like that (but I take whole pipeline log, not current stage log)

```
if(manager.logContains(".*FAILURES*")) {
    currentStage.result = 'FAILURE'
}
```

Comment: Using Jenkins API, you can enumerate all `FlowNode`s (aka steps) of the current stage, retrieve their `LogStorageAction`, write the log to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, convert to string and then parse it to determine your stage status. I have some experimental code for that, but it currently prints logs out of order. If I find some time I will fix that and post an answer later.

Comment: Do you really need whole stage log or would it be sufficient to work with the log of a shell step?

Comment: I think the log of shell step will be sufficient

Comment: Then you can just write something like `def log = sh returnStdout: true, script: "echo Test"`. The variable `log` will contain all output of shell step which you can further process using regular expressions. I may write a more complete answer later.